# How to unit test a call to a function called when subscribing to an ActivatedRoute data?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, observable, angular2-routing

I want to unit test the ngOnInit() method of a component in my Angular app. The ngOnInit() method subscribes to the ActivatedRoute `data` and calls a function inside the subscribe method. Here's the code of the method:

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.data.subscribe(data => this.store.patchState(data));
}
```

Here's my test :

**component.spec.ts**

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(xyzComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

it('#ngOnInit should call patchState', async(() => {

    const spy = spyOn(store, 'patchState');

    // When
    component.ngOnInit();

    fixture.detectChanges();

    // Then
    expect(spy.calls.count()).toBe(1, 'patchState has been called once.');

  }));
```

However when I run the test I get an error telling me that 'Expected spy patchState was never called.'

I believe my problem is coming from the asynchronous nature of the test but I can't figure out why it won't work.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Change the subscription to :

```
this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
                                   console.log('in route subscription);
                                   this.store.patchState(data)
                         });
```

If you don't see the `console.log('in route subscription')`, it seems that you may not be mocking the `activatedRoute` correctly.

Try this:

```
describe('xyzComponent', () => {
  let store: Store<...>; // for you to fill out
  let component: xyzComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<xyzComponent>;
  let data$ = new BehaviorSubject({ x: 1 }); // mock data for activatedRoute

  beforeEach(async() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ StoreModule.forRoot(....) ], // for you to fill out
      declarations: [ XYZComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { data: data$ } },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = TestBed.get(store);
    spyOn(store, 'patchState').and.callThrough(); // and.callThrough() is optional, do you want it to HAVE both a spy and call the actual implementation?
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(xyzComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges(); // this fixture.detectChanges() will call `ngOnInit` for us, so we don't have to manually call it
  });

  it('ngOnInit should call patchState', () => {
    expect(store.patchState).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ x: 1 });
  });
});
```

That should hopefully get you unblocked. You can also change `route.data` in later tests and see how it would react by doing `data.next$({....})` your future value.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to look into it and answer, the problem was indeed coming from the mocked activatedRoute! Thanks again, regards!